# Send Feedback using php form

Tags: php, html

I want to send Feedback from from to my email address. I have write following code. But when I press submit nothing happen.

```
<?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="") { 
/* display the contact form */
?>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input class="inputst" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="s_name"><br>
        <input class="inputst" type="email" placeholder="Your Email" name="s_email"><br>
        <input class="inputst" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" name="s_mobile"><br>
        <input class="inputst" type="text" placeholder="Delivery Address" name="s_address"><br>
        <input class="inputst" name="s_link" type="text" value="http://alutamarket.com/boutique-and-fashion-store/phones-tabs-accessories/samsung-galaxy-note-3_i3" name="productlink"><br>
        <div style="margin-top:20px;"><a type="submit" class="im-contac"><span class="im-top">Send Now</span><span class="im-bot">Send inquiry now</span><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></a></div>
    </form>
<?php
} else {
    /* send the submitted data */
    $name=$_REQUEST['s_name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['s_email'];
    $mobile=$_REQUEST['s_mobile'];
    $address=$_REQUEST['s_address'];
    $message=$_REQUEST['s_link'];
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($mobile=="")||($address=="")||($message=="")) {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
    } else {        
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
        mail("myemail@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
        echo "Email sent!";
    }
}  
?>
```

I want to send one copy email to sender also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes Required**

**1)** create a submit to submit form

**2)** check isset that submit button is clicked or not

Try This

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name=$_POST['s_name'];
    $email=$_POST['s_email'];
    $mobile=$_POST['s_mobile'];
    $address=$_POST['s_address'];
    $message=$_POST['s_link'];
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($mobile=="")||($address=="")||($message=="")) {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
    } else {       
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
        mail("myemail@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
        echo "Email sent!";
    }
} 
?>

<?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="") {
    /* display the contact form */
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input class="inputst" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="s_name"><br>
        <input class="inputst" type="email" placeholder="Your Email" name="s_email"><br>
        <input class="inputst" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" name="s_mobile"><br>
        <input class="inputst" type="text" placeholder="Delivery Address" name="s_address"><br>
        <input class="inputst" name="s_link" type="text" value="http://alutamarket.com/boutique-and-fashion-store/phones-tabs-accessories/samsung-galaxy-note-3_i3" name="productlink"><br>
        <div style="margin-top:20px;"><button type="submit" name="submit" class="im-contac"><span class="im-top">Send Now</span><span class="im-bot">Send inquiry now</span><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button></div>
    </form>
<?php 
}
?>
```